# Arithmetics in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, lua, luacode, directlua

I have the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} 
\begin{luacode}
function fact(n)
 if n == 0 then
          return 1
        else
           tex.sprint ( n * fact(n - 1) )
        end
      end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\factorial[1]{\directlua{fact(#1)}}
\begin{document}
\factorial{5}
\end{document}
```

This throws the error that attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value. Where is the problem?

Comment: Your lua function returns nothing if n!=0. So fact(n-1) is nil.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the code you posted, evaluating `fact(5)` causes the following expression to be evaluated by the Lua interpreter inside LuaTeX:

```lua
tex.sprint(5*fact(4))
```

which is

```lua
tex.sprint(
  5*tex.sprint(
    4*fact(3)))
```

which is

```lua
tex.sprint(
  5*tex.sprint(
    4*tex.sprint(
      3*fact(2))))
```

which is

```lua
tex.sprint(
  5*tex.sprint(
    4*tex.sprint(
      3*tex.sprint(
        2*fact(1)))))
```

which is

```lua
tex.sprint(
  5*tex.sprint(
    4*tex.sprint(
      3*tex.sprint(
        2*tex.sprint(
          1*fact(0))))))
```

which is

```lua
tex.sprint(
  5*tex.sprint(
    4*tex.sprint(
      3*tex.sprint(
        2*tex.sprint(
          1*1)))))
```

The first `fact()` call to return a value when the Lua interpreter evaluates `fact(5)` is thus `fact(0)`. According to your definition of `fact()`, this evaluates to the Lua integer `1`. Then `1*1` is evaluated, results in the Lua integer `1`, and the next recursion level thus tries to evaluate `2*tex.sprint(1)`. This is where your code fails, since `tex.sprint(1)` evaluates to `nil` and `2*nil` isn't a valid arithmetic expression (`tex.sprint()` prints contents to the DVI or PDF output, but as a Lua function, returns `nil`). Because of this error, the recursion stops.

You can fix the problem this way:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function fact(n)
 if n == 0 then
    return 1
 else
    return n * fact(n - 1)
 end
end

function printfact(n)
  tex.sprint (fact(n))
end

\end{luacode}

\newcommand*{\factorial}[1]{\directlua{printfact(#1)}}

\begin{document}
\factorial{5}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output (DVI or PDF):

[image]

In this code, the `fact()` function always returns a Lua number (not `nil`), while `printfact()` writes the corresponding number to the TeX output file (DVI or PDF).

Answer (score 4):

Here's my recommendation: Move the `tex.sprint` directive to the definition of the `\factorial` macro, and use `return`, not `tex.sprint`, to return numbers from the `fact` function.

Note also that since there are no TeX-special characters (such as `#`, `%`, and `\`) in the setup of the Lua function `fact`, one can define it via a `\directlua` call, as is done in the code below. No need, in this case, to load the `luacode` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{
```

```lua
function fact ( n )
   if n == 0 or n == 1 then
       return 1
   else
       return ( n * fact (n - 1) )
   end
end
```

```tex
}

\newcommand\factorial[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(fact(#1))}}

\begin{document}
\factorial{5}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function printfact(n)
  if n == 0 then n = 1 end
  for i=2, n-1 do n=n*i end
  tex.sprint(n)
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand*\factorial[1]{\directlua{printfact(#1)}}

\begin{document}
    \factorial{5}
\end{document}
```